# How can I get super detailed Django debug info?

Tags: django, python-3.x, debugging

I have a very difficult to diagnose Django problem in which sometimes the server locks up for a period of time many attempts to debug it have not succeeded.

So I need to see at the most detailed level possible what Python is doing.

Ideally I would have some sort of output log sitting somewhere dumping vast amounts of info the the screen until the problem occurs then I can see exactly what was happening at the point of hang.

Can anyone suggest the most effective way to get this information dumped out of Django?  All the searches that I do for Django debugging refer only to application level debugging - I need to go lower.

UPDATE:

I found this and will give it a try:

```
python -m trace -t manage.py runserver --noreload
```

Comment: You may also try `cProfile` to get a .profile file that you can exploit with `snakeviz`.